# Box API returns 404 error for folder collaborated or shared by outside user

Tags: box-api

Have a situation where an outside user collaborates or shares a folder with a enterprise user. API call impersonating the enterprise user returns a 404 error. Please see the http exchange below using curl. Some sensitive information is masked. Appreciate any help.

curl -k -v -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" -H "As-User: 2146XXXXX"         https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/1834XXXXXX

```
* About to connect() to api.box.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 74.112.185.97... connected
> GET /2.0/folders/1834XXXXXX HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: api.box.com
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
> As-User: 2146XXXXX
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: nginx
< Date: Wed, 16 Apr 2014 00:34:58 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 323
< Connection: keep-alive
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.box.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
{"type":"error","status":404,"code":"not_found","context_info":{"errors":     [{"reason":"invalid_parameter","name":"item","message":"Invalid value 'd_1834XXXXXX'. 'item' with value 'd_1834XXXXXX' not found"}]},"help_url":"http:\/\/developers.box.com\/docs\/#errors","message":"Not  Found","request_id":"1378003773534dd03193806"}
```